# is this the proper way to use initialization?

Tags: swift

Right so I always initialize with a function, but I'm new to this swift initialization so is this way that I initialized this 2d array proper.

```
var board = [[UIButton]](){
   init(array:UIButton){
       board = [
          [b0,b1,b2],
          [b3,b4,b5],
          [b6,b7,b8]

    ] 
  }
}
```

Comment: :O Surely that doesn't compile, which is a clue that it's not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `board` variable must be initialised with an array of buttons, so in the class that contains your board, you specify an `init(boardButtons:)` initializer that initializes the `board` variable:

```
class ClassThatContainsBoard {

    var board: [[UIButton]]

    init(boardButtons: [UIButton]) {
        let b = boardButtons
        board = [
            [b[0], b[1], b[2]],
            [b[3], b[4], b[5]],
            [b[6], b[7], b[8]]
        ]
    }
}
```

If your class itself knows what buttons should comprise the board, you needn't specify an initializer that takes the buttons as a parameter. Variables can take a closure to initialize themselves to a default value:

```
class ClassThatContainsBoard {

    var board: [[UIButton]] = {
        var numRows = 3
        var numCols = 3
        var newBoard = [[UIButton]]()

        for row in 0..<numRows {
            var boardRow = [UIButton]()

            for col in 0..<numCols {
                let buttonNumber = (row + 1) * (col + 1)
                let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
                button.setTitle("\(buttonNumber)", forState: .Normal)
                boardRow.append(button)
            }

            newBoard.append(boardRow)
        }

        return newBoard
    }()
}
```

So above, when an instance of `ClassThatContainsBoard` is initialized, the closure will be executed and return the default value for `board`. Here, it's just initialised to a 3x3 array of buttons, with each button's title set to the numbered position on the board.

Comment: @frosty Not at all, any new language takes time to get used to. [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) is a great resource for learning Swift, such as the different ways to initialise variables.